# Setting up a Sails JS app with Postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I am absolutely new to Postgres. I have previously set up a sails app using MongoDB as the underlying database. It was quite simple. However, with postgres, I am facing some issues.

I am following [this](http://rok3.me/blog/configuring-postgresql-sails-jsjade/) tutorial

Here are the contents of my config/local.js file

```
//config/local.js
 
module.exports = {
 
  port: process.env.PORT || 1337,
   
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
 
  adapters: {
 
    'default': 'postgres',
 
    postgres: {
      module   : 'sails-postgresql',
      host     : 'localhost',
      port     : 5432,
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'postgres',
 
      schema: true //This makes sure that sails matches 
                   //the database schema to your models.
    }
 
  }
 
};
```

When I run sails lift with verbose logs, The process gets stuck at the following stage:

```
verbose: Grunt :: 
Running "sails-linker:devTplJADE" (sails-linker) task

verbose: Grunt :: 

verbose: Grunt :: Running "watch" task

verbose: Grunt :: Waiting...
```

Any help ?

**EDIT:**

It's working now. Had to create a unix user with the same name as postgre user and db.

Now the porblem is, I want to create a table with two columns

CREATE TABLE users (
user_id serial,
user_name varchar(50)
);

I create this schema in postgre. The when I submit a POST request, it overrides the schema. I don't want that to happen. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the schema in the `models` folder. In there, you create a file for each model with the proper attributes. When you `sails lift`, Sails will populate your database for you.

Check out http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models for some more information.

Comment: Found that setting migrate: 'safe' will keep the existing schema if the table is already defined

Comment: That works as well. Though if you do create new models in the future, it's probably better to do them through Sails rather than manually creating them in SQL.